# How many queens can be on a chessboard without attacking each other?

Tags: checkerboard, chess

What is the maximum number of queens that can be placed on a standard 8x8 chessboard such that no one of them is capable of attacking any of the others in a single move?

Comment: See related discussion at meta http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/63/are-two-person-strategy-games-on-or-off-topic

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> 8.

Because:

> Obviously, you can't have more than 8, since you would have a row (and column) with more than one queen on it.

According to [Wolfram-Alpha](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QueensProblem.html), there are

> 12 unique solutions, plus an additional 80 solutions from rotation/reflection.

One possible solution is:

> [image: 8 Queens not attacking each other. Image from codereview.stackexchange.com]

A list (and images!) of all

> 12 base solutions can be found both at the above Wolfram-Alpha link and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle).  (Thank you [Kevin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4/kevin) for the link).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle

Answer (score 18):

Sorry for reviving a 5 years old question, but I can fit:

> 16 queens

I hope to avoid downvotes by pointing out that this troll solution satisfies all the conditions of the original question.

> ([image]

Comment: Is there *really* a point to necroing a 5 year old question with a response you openly acknowledge is a troll answer that clearly doesn't address the intent of the question? Please don't.

Comment: A troll solution is still a solution. Take it as an oportunity to see the importance of a good design in puzzle creation and an example of thinking out of the box.

Comment: Just missing to approve that it is the maximal solution.(+1)

Comment: Why is this a troll solution? Seems perfectly reasonable to me

Comment: Yes, pawns are not prohibited in the question, nice creative thinking!

Comment: @Rubio - given that the point of this site is entertainment, I would say this is a great answer. There are many questions (especially with the riddle tag) where the funny yet obviously wrong answers are sometimes the most fun of all, especially when they fit within the parameters of the puzzle. I'm pretty sure I have my fair share of them. [Here's one.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/33734/17024)