# A "What Am I" riddle about a thing

Tags: riddle

Here we go:

```
I can be sneaky,

I can have thorns,

I can even be a coward,

I can be thick or thin, live or dead,

AND I can play classical music.
```

**What Am I?**

HINT:

> I can be brush. (Courtesy of Chad W's answer and my dyslexia)

I really thought this one would be answered by now so here's another HINT:

> I can be hay.

Comment: This is the longest it's taken for someone to get one of my riddles.  Maybe the third line was a bit harsh. :)

Comment: *Tap tap tap* ...Anyone got an answer?

Comment: How about a bounty then? :)

Comment: Is " Tap tap tap " a hint? :)

Comment: @smriti Maaaaaybe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is

> Wire

I can be sneaky,

> Wire-tap - to obtain information by tapping a telephone.

I can have thorns,

> Barbed wire has barbs or thorns.

I can even be a coward,

> Chicken wire  - light wire netting with a hexagonal mesh.

I can be thick or thin,

> Wire can be obtained both thick and thin.

live

> Live wire - an energetic and unpredictable person.

or dead,

> Dead wire is electrical wire that does not carry current.

AND I can play classical music.

> Piano Wire or "Music Wire" (Thanks Jasen)

Hint 1

> Wire brush - a brush with steel wire bristles.

Hint 2

> Haywire - erratic or out of control.

Comment: Finally!  Yep.  Think what you'd call a coward.  Maybe yellow or _______?  Maybe I could edit to complete the explanations?

Comment: I'll give it one more try to clean up some of the answers, if that's okay.

Comment: Sure.  Looking pretty good already (there's a slightly better fit for music though)

Comment: piano and harp strings are this stuff

Comment: @hexomino For sneaky you could have also had a ____ that you wear, or a trip____.

Comment: @Jasen Piano ____ was exactly what I was thinking of with the classical music line. +1

Answer (score 9):

You are a:

> Hedgehog

I can be sneaky,

> A hedgehog can be sneaky.

I can have thorns,

> A hedgehog has thorns (actually they are called spines or quills, but they are thorn-like).

I can even be a coward,

> A hedgehog can be a coward and curl into a ball, particularly when an owl is nearby.

I can be thick or thin, live or dead,

> This is probably true of all mammals.

AND I can play classical music.

> Obviously...
>  http://www.classicfm.com/discover/music/marutaro-hedgehog-piano/

Comment: I love this answer but its not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hehe. Yeah, I figured it wasn't right...

Answer (score 1):

You are a:

> Stick

You can be sneaky:

> Sticks can trip you if you don't see them on the ground

You can have thorns:

> Some sticks have thorns

You can be a coward:

> A bit confused about this

You can be thick or thin, live or dead:

> A stick can be thick or thin, it can be on its tree(live) or fallen off (dead)

You can play classical music:

> The conductor's baton

Comment: It's not the answer.  Sorry.  Some good explanations though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is:

> Oboe

You can be sneaky and you can have a thorn:

> A fugitive is sneaky and there's the story of Androcles and the Lion, a.k.a The Shepherd and the Lion. In the story Androcles removes a thorn from a Lion's paw and becomes it's "friend".

You can even play Classical Music:

> A Shepherd's instrument can be a pipe, and between the various types of pipes instruments there is the Oboe.

You can be a coward:

> Oboe is also the name of a British aerial blind bombing targeting system in World War II, which operated with a certain number of transmitters in the ground and a Oboe Operator managed the system from safe ground... Maybe the operator could be described as coward, or the targeting system itself can be described as coward? This Oboe system can also be described as sneaky.

You can be thick or thin, live or dead:

> Thick as a person(the operator) or even the aircrafts maybe... And thin as a pipe and obviously dead and live can refer to dead as pipe(an object) or live as the Oboe operator/Oboist(Oboe player)???

Comment: Sorry, I'd never even heard of an oboe.  :/

Comment: :p Well... At least i tried. :D

Comment: And an educational try it was too!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is:

> "bush", as in the plant and President Bush

edit:

> Classic Composer Geoffrey Bush - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoffrey_Bush

Comment: Yikes, Sorry.  I read this wrong.  If you'd said brush that would've been a good clue.

Comment: Thick and thin, coward, sneaky, etc.  Not a bad try when I think about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the answer, although I may well be wrong,

> Toothbrush<

I am sneaky

> You can easily hide a toothbrush<

I can have thorns

> It perhaps means the bristles<

I can be a coward

> You don't fight with a toothbrush.(Not sure about that)<

I can be thick or thin, live or dead

> Toothbrushes can be of any size or shape. For the dead or live part, In early days, twigs were used as toothbrushes as well.<

I can play classical Music

> Toothpick is another name for Doug Ray who is a singer<

It's not completely foolproof. But, Would love to know the answer.
P.S. Your hint helped a lot.

Comment: It's not a toothbrush.  I wont leave this answerless forever.  I did think someone would have it by now though so I'll give it a while longer before I cough it up.